# Запятые в массивах

Tags: массивы, javascript

Доброго всем

```
my_array = new Array("text_field_1",
"text_field_2",
"text_field_3",
"text_field_4",
"text_field_5");

document.write(my_array);
```

на выходе:

> text_field_1,text_field_2,text_field_3,text_field_4,text_field_5,

Вопрос: зачем запятые прорисовываются?
Я заметил, что массив, если писать через "+", то без запятых, но это же конкатенация получается уже, а не массив.

Comment: У вас недопонимание, как работает JavaScript.

Плюс - это склейка строк. Запятая же означает перечисление.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

так работает метод toString.
Вы можете нарисовать любой свой метод, сам массив от этого пострадать не должен: любое отдельно взятое значение лишних запятых не содержит.

```
my_array.toString = function(){
  return this.join(' '); // внутри функции join в кавычках указан склеивающий символ. Сейчас - пробел. 
}
```

Comment: Помедленнее, я зап-п-писываю...
Я просто в JS ещё совсем "зелёный".
Как это нарисовать свой метод?

Comment: Если отдельно для ЭТОГО массива, то так(см апдейт).
Если для всех массивов(что не рекомендуется), то через
Array.prototype.toString

Comment: @knes, это все, конечно, круто, но зачем? Видно же что ТС начинающий, so keep it simple:


     document.write(my_array.join(' '));

через Array.prototype.toString? четко...

Comment: Вот как рас джойном и заджойнил
var str = out_block_3.join('\n');

Comment: Array.prototype.toString не надо менять.

Comment: не надо. Но возможность такая имеется. ;)